# Chess in Java - Object orientation vs Efficiency

Tags: java, oop, chess

I'm developing a chess program in Java and considering the following problem:

- The Rook piece requires implementation for moving in straight lines.
- The Bishop piece requires implementation for moving in diagonal lines.

However,

- The Queen piece requires implementation for both of the above movement patterns.

I can't think of a clean solution to modelling this relationship, I have considered some but none of them are both compliant with good object-orientated design *and* code efficient.

1. Java doesn't support multiple inheritance, so Queen cannot borrow implementation from Rook and Bishop
2. If Rook and Bishop extended Queen, I'd need to extract the logic for each kind of movement into separate methods, this would serious bloat my current design for how movement is validated.

Neither of the above solutions seem elegant enough to beat just:

3. Putting ALL of the movement implementation into the parent class of all the pieces, this way they all can share *all* of the common implementation (of which there is quite a bit)

I'm aware solution 3 is in violation of good Java design, but in this case, that design pattern seems to only be forcing bloated, inelegant solutions.

Probably this could be avoided with a complete restructuring of the program, but everything up to this point looks pretty efficient to me, does good OO design always come at the cost of directness of functionality and structure? Is my approach just wrong for the style of the language?

How would you solve this problem?

Comment: When dealing with the final, real implementation, I always choose efficiency over good standards and whatnot. That said, as has been already suggested, you could externalize each movement in its own class instance, then give each piece the movement / movements it needs.

Comment: There is more than just subclassing. Use interfaces and delegation!

Comment: Remember, current design guidelines suggest favouring composition over inheritance. Why not have straight line and diagonal move generator classes and have the piece classes use them? Having said that, if you are writing an actual playing engine here then forget about objects for pieces and go with a bit board - you'll need it for the speed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**While some classes might behave in a similar way, this does not automatically mean that they are in one hierarchy!**

For example, both a `Human` and a `Crab` can move sideways, but it is silly for a `Human` to extend `Crab`.

If you really want to re-use movement code, you can use encapsulation, use a `Movement` type and make it like this:

```
class Human
{
   List<Movement> movements;
}

class Crab
{
    List<Movement> movements;
}

class MoveSideWays extends Movement
{
      move();
}

class MoveForward extends Movement
{
      move();
}
```

But it feels like over-engineering. I would have a `Piece` class with `getPossibleMoves()` and just implement it directly. There is not too much overlap and Rooks have specialized movements (Castling) as well.

```
class Rook extends Piece
{
   List<Move> getPossibleMoves()  {...}
}

class Queen extends Piece
{
   List<Move> getPossibleMoves() {...}
}
```

Comment: I agree, I'd rather make a hierarchy of `Movement`s than chess pieces

Comment: The point is to have only one place where your code for moveing is kept. This prevents code duplication and makes your implementation less error prone to code changes which influnes many other entities, so you don't need to look somehere else for the same piece of code if you want to change your movement-algorithm. I would agree with whis solution :-)

Comment: @Westranger this case is an interesting case, because you do not want to repeat yourself, while on the other hand, want simple, maintainable code. Abstracting away how the pieces move makes it a little harder to see what they can do directly and makes it harder to code the exceptions (rook -> castling). Because there will never be other chess-pieces, the value of the abstraction is not that great (you can only reuse Bishop and Rook parts for Queen). I would not bother and keep it as simple as possible. Both solutions will work and both are, IMHO, ok. Just a matter of taste :)

Comment: Accepted, this seems like the best approach to me, thanks for your input.

Answer (score 4):

You should not add a superclass-subclass relations to the individual pieces. The Queen is not the special case of the Rook, neither the Rook is the special case of the Queen. They are just different pieces. You may create an interface (or an abstract class) `Piece` and provide different implementations like `Rook`, `Bishop`, `Queen` and so on.

Answer (score 1):

You could move both methods to the superclass, but make them `protected static` (you could also put those methods in a `PieceHelper`). In the subclasses you can then implement the adequate methods, referencing to one or the other of those methods (making them `public`).

Superclass:

```
abstract class Piece {
    protected static void moveStraight(Piece p) {...}
    protected static void moveDiagonal(Piece p) {...}
}
```

(Optional) Interfaces:

```
interface DiagonalMover {
     void moveDiagonal();
}
interface StraightMover {
     void moveStraight();
}
```

Subclasses:

```
class Rook extends Piece implements StraightMover {
    public void moveStraight() {Piece.moveStraight(this);}
}
class Bishop extends Piece implements DiagonalMover {
    public void moveDiagonal() {Piece.moveDiagonal(this);}
}
class Queen extends Piece implements StraightMover, DiagonalMover {
    public void moveStraight() {Piece.moveStraight(this);}
    public void moveDiagonal() {Piece.moveDiagonal(this);}
}
```

Comment: This violates the Liskov principle... (see: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/solid-part-3-liskov-substitution-interface-segregation-principles--net-36710)

Comment: @RobAu True. I updated my code: the methods of the superclass are now `static`.

Answer (score 0):

Straight line and diagonal movements are behaviors
Thus they can be modeled using interface more fittingly than inheritance

Rookie implements StraightMovement

Bishiop implements DiagonalMovement

Queen implements StraightMovement,DiagonalMovement

Answer (score -1):

> Java doesn't support multiple inheritance, so Queen cannot borrow implementation from Rook and Bishop

You don't need multiple inheritance. A lot of that can be simulated with default methods.

Comment: The link does not lead to any useful article, just getting redirected to a company's home page.